# How can i order my data Ascending by Time

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sorting

Like said in the title I am trying to sort my data from sqlite database to ascending time. Here is what I have so far:

```
Cursor display = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TableName  + " ORDER BY Time ASC",null );
```

It displays data however it doesnt sort according to my Time with formade ##.## 24hr time. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Show some example data.

Comment: Could you add the database schema and its data types?

Answer (score -1):

Try `"SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " ORDER BY time(Time)"`. PS: ASC is default ;)

Comment: ty for the suggestion however the problem still wasnt fixed. Is it anything to do my with Time variable in helper class. my column name for time is Time

Comment: `time()` is an function, which calculate a integer from your String `Time`. For me it works. Please rename `Time` to `timestring`, because `time` is an protected Key.

Comment: Hello user7388968, i think you have to learn a little bit basics, bevor you dislike my Answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [strftime()](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
ORDER BY strftime('%H:%M:%S',my_column)
```

Here I created a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d3e7d/28) as example.

The raw query should be something like:

```
"SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " ORDER BY strftime('%H:%M:%S'," + my_column + ")"
```

**NOTE:** `strftime()` function is the more general function that you can use for manipulate date. But, for this specific case you can also use `time()`. Indeed, as the document that I linked says:

`time(...)` is equivalent to    `strftime('%H:%M:%S', ...)`